# Combine json objects in array in node js

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, loops

I am making a call to a function that returns an array with JSON objects:

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
fileImport(userImport)
    .then ((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      resolve(response);
    })
})

result:
    [
      { users: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ], errors: [] },
      { users: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ], errors: [] } 
    ]
```

I want to combine the objects into a single JSON object.
I tried iterating through the array, but am getting a strange response:

```
for (const file in response) {
        console.log(file);
}
result:
0
1
```

I have no idea where the 0 1 comes from (the keys of the objects in the array? No idea).
How can I combine the two objects or at least iterate through each so I can manually combine them with a loop?

Comment: Important technical note: there are no "json objects", there's JSON, which is a string representation of a JS data object, and there are normal objects. You're working with normal objects. As for why you're getting that strange response: show us, but mostly yourself, what `response` actually looks like, because it sounds like it's not what your code expects it to be.

Comment: The code you've given is not a minimal reproducible example so it's very hard to help you based on what you've given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misplaced `"in"` keyword instead of `"of"` in for loop.

Try this

```js
for (const file of response) {
        console.log(file);
}
```

Comment: Where is the facepalm emoji when I need one? This is why I shouldn't write code when I'm tired. And I use this loop like every 5 lines of code... Thanks!